# How do I get Eclipse navigator to refocus, based on a new level of filter in mylyn?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I  am currently using eclipse and Mylyn. My problem is that when I change the level of interest required for an item to show up in mylyn context, I cannot get eclipse navigator to accept the new settings. In fact, if I close the task and open it again, the degree of interest meter-thingy has reset itself. The only solution I can find is to *Delete invisible elements*, but that is too permanent to be to my liking. Does anyone know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I can clear things up for you.  Hope this helps!

**Summary:** In the Task Editor there is a tab that allows you to view a task's context with adjustable filtering but it does not effect the Navigator or Package Explorer.

**Details:** Mylyn allows you to view all of the files that are in the context of a given task by looking at the "Context" tab in the Task Editor (shown below for an email task).

[image: Context Slider]

In the screenshot above you use the slider to choose the threshold for the level of interest required for a file to appear.  If the slider is all the way to the left all files in the task's context will appear and as you move it right the files will start to become filtered.  However, this slider only effects the "Context" tab and does not effect the Navigator or Package Explorer.  This slider value is not persistant and, as you noticed, will be reset upon reopening the task.  The slider was created so that developers could review the files in their context prior to submission.

David Shepherd, Tasktop Technologies
http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. I wish I could apply the slider, but at least I will no longer be confused. Thanks again.